# getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView() is not working

Tags: php, facebook-php-webdriver, php-webdriver

in version [php-webdriver 1.6](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) `getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView()` is working fine, when currently I updated my **version 1.8** it's giving me an error:

> FAILED: Exception occurred : unknown command: Cannot call non W3C
>   standard command while in W3C mode

why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [php-webdriver 1.11.1](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1111---2021-05-21).

It is true the method is not part of the W3C WebDriver protocol, but its behavior was re-implemented as a polyfill, so you can now use the `getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView()` method both the old and the new protocol, without a need to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

`getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView()` is no longer supported in W3C WebDriver protocol

I found an [alternative solution](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/issues/794#issuecomment-631626080) for scroll, which works like this `getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView()`

```
$element = $driver->findElement($by);
$action = new WebDriverActions($this->driver);
$action->moveToElement($element);
$action->perform();
```

Note: It is available at **version 1.8**, will not work in [php-webdriver 1.6](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver)